# Pandas: Do average from each cell

Tags: python, pandas, average

From and object column (each cell of the column seems to me a like a matrix with two numbers) I want to perform the average of each cell:

```
> appid      new_owners     
> 10     [10000000, 20000000] 
> 20     [5000000, 10000000]
> 30     [5000000, 10000000] 
> 40     [5000000, 10000000] 
> 50     [5000000, 10000000]
```

Now what i want would be something like:

```
> appid      new_owners     
> 10          15000000 
> 20          7500000
> 30          7500000
> 40          7500000
> 50          7500000
```

Comment: `df["new_owners"].apply( lambda data: int(sum(data)/len(data)) )`

Comment: `df["new_owners"].apply( lambda data: int(numpy.average(data)) )` or even `df["new_owners"].apply(numpy.average).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics
df = pd.DataFrame({"appid":[10,20,30,40,50],"new_owners":[[10000000, 20000000], [5000000, 10000000], [5000000, 10000000], [5000000, 10000000], [5000000, 10000000]]})
df["new_owners"] = df["new_owners"].apply(statistics.mean)
print(df)
```

output

```
   appid  new_owners
0     10    15000000
1     20     7500000
2     30     7500000
3     40     7500000
4     50     7500000
```

Explanation: I have used [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and `statistics.mean` function (`statistics` is part of `python` standard library)

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on [Daweo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10785975/daweo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72163890/395857) to handle the case where  each cell contains a list of *strings* (and not floats or integers):

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics

mapping_dict = {'A':['1','2','3'], 'B':['3','4','5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(mapping_dict.items()),columns=['Key','Value'])
print(df["Value"])

df["Value"] = df["Value"].apply(lambda s: list(map(float, s)))
df["Value"] = df["Value"].apply(statistics.mean)
print(df["Value"])
```

Output:

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [3, 4, 5]
Name: Value, dtype: object

0    2.0
1    4.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```